# Client Request Timeout between SenecaJS Service and Express API

Tags: node.js, express, timeout, client, seneca

I am using SenecaJS to build a microservices based application. So far, I have conceptualized one microservice which consists of only one action yet. This action, when called, will execute a time-consuming shell command (approx. time consumed 3 minutes) and return as a response - the output of the shell command. My code files are available here: https://gist.github.com/ohmtrivedi/5a94841d25714f3cfd6aee260add97bb

So, I have been trying to make requests to this service in 2 different ways: First, I send a direct request to the service (which runs the plugin, `osfp_tool`) using cURL and as demonstrated here: http://senecajs.org/getting-started/#writing-microservices.
Second, by referencing this tutorial: http://senecajs.org/getting-started/#web-server-integration, I wrote an Express API which communicates with my service (`osfp_service`). So, I send HTTP requests (using POSTMAN) to the Express API.

I used to receive Client Request timeout error in both cases. After some research, I came to know of timeout configuration in Seneca instance. So, I added a time configuration at 2 places - in the Seneca service (`osfp_service`) as well as in the Express API (`app.js`). Note that, I have set timeout to 300000ms or 5 mins. I have checked that the shell command takes about 3 mins, so timeout is set more than that. However, I still face Client Request timeout error as you can see below. I know that there is no error from the shell command execution, as on my serivce log, even after I get Client timeout Request error, the action completes its execution successfully which can be seen using console.log messages.

[image: Log of script execution when attempting to send request directly to the service]

Hope someone can help me in resolving this issue, stuck on it for a very long time now.

**EDIT**
So, I have been playing around with timeout configuration. I was able to resolve the timeout error from `osfp_service.js` script by setting the timeout in seneca instance at the topmost level (https://gist.github.com/ohmtrivedi/5a94841d25714f3cfd6aee260add97bb#file-osfp_service-js-L8).

If I set timeout configuration in `app.js` in the same way (https://gist.github.com/ohmtrivedi/5a94841d25714f3cfd6aee260add97bb#file-app2-js-L26), then I still get Error 504: Client request timeout/Gateway timeout (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1El2JCy047dnm6PHlvU33d_mKPuIWUlfX).

If I set timeout configuration in `app.js` inside the transport object in seneca instance (https://gist.github.com/ohmtrivedi/5a94841d25714f3cfd6aee260add97bb#file-app1-js-L26), then I get Error 503: Response timeout/Service Unavailable (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u6w7XyK9-vAJVhna_JnIQ4imRzOm_51T). I cannot understand why it says Service Unavailable, because the action does get executed and it even completes successfully.

I can't seem to understand the different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also worked on timeout problems with Seneca.
For **my** application, the solution was:

1. Set the timeout in require('seneca'):

   ```
   let seneca = require('seneca')(
     {
       timeout: config.request_timeout,
       tag: ...
     }
   )
   ```
2. Set the timeout in each act() call:

   ```
   seneca.act({timeout$: config.request_timeout, role: ...});
   ```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

As found in [this post](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca/issues/385#issuecomment-356997823), the transport timeout can also be configured:

```
let seneca = require('seneca')(
  {
    timeout: config.request_timeout,
    tag: ...,
    transport: {
      'web': { timeout: config.request_timeout },
      'tcp': { timeout: config.request_timeout }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: So @jack-y, I tried to make a request to my osfp_service.js (not via Express API) as follows: `curl -d '{"timeout$": 300000, "role":"osfp_tool", "cmd":"fp_os", "remote_ip":"222.136.147.76"}' http://localhost:80/act`. But, I still got `{ "code": "ETIMEDOUT" }` as response. Still the action does gets completed on its side.

Comment: Hi @jack-y, setting transport timeout at all the places (transport timeout, seneca timeout and even in seneca.act call) does work but not always. So, I have set the timeout for 5 mins (300000) because as mentioned the action takes at max 3 mins. But sometimes, the app.js script fails with **statusCode: 502, error: Bad Gateway, message: Client request error: socket hang up**. I have updated my gist with the current version of code. Hope you have some idea about it.